# How to handle Processing instructions in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I want to do some tasks using `XSLT 2.0`. I have explained my using following example.

Input:

```
<code>
    <bigin>
        <?codestuct a?>
        <butic>
            <a>a</a>
            <a>b</a>
        </butic>
        <?codestuct c?>
        <butic>
            <a>a</a>
            <a>b</a>
        </butic>
    </bigin>
    <medium>
        <?codestuct a?>
        <super>
            <p>para1</p>
        </super>
        <?codestuct b?>
        <super>
            <p>para2</p>
        </super>
        <?codestuct c?>
        <super>
            <p>para3</p>
        </super>
    </medium>
</code>
```

What I wanted to was add string if `<super>` processing-instruction equals to the `<butic>` processing-instruction.

As an example,

1st `<super>` element processing-instruction equals to 1st `<butic>` processing-instruction. Then `found` string should be printed in output.

But 2nd `<super>` element processing-instruction not equals to any `<butic>` element.

Expected output:

```
<output>
    <extreme>Founded</extreme>
    <extreme>Not Founded</extreme>
    <extreme>Founded</extreme>
</output>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template match="medium">
    <output>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::bigin/processing-instruction('codestuct') = super/processing-instruction('codestuct')">
                <extreme>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Founded'"/>
                </extreme>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <extreme>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Not Founded'"/>
                </extreme>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </output>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not quite clear what you want to compare and whether the elements matter but

```
  <xsl:template match="code">
      <output>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="medium/processing-instruction()"/>
      </output>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="medium/processing-instruction()">
      <extreme>Not found</extreme>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="medium/processing-instruction()[some $pi in /code/bigin/processing-instruction() satisfies deep-equal(., $pi)]">
      <extreme>Found</extreme>
  </xsl:template>
```

gives

```
<output>
   <extreme>Found</extreme>
   <extreme>Not found</extreme>
   <extreme>Found</extreme>
</output>
```

at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ei5R4uG

Answer (score 2):

A processing instruction has a name and a value. For `<?codestuct a?>` the name is `codestuct` and the value is `a`. When you use the "=" operator, then (like with elements) you are only comparing the value, not the name. If you want both parts to be equal, use deep-equal(), or compare them separately: `name($x) = name($y) and string($x) = string($y)`